# Redirecting logs from component using commons logging through application log4j.xml

Tags: logging, log4j, apache-commons-logging

I am new to logging mechanisms , hence pardon me if my question seems naive.

I am using log4j in my web application, but one of the components used uses a customer logger, say A that implements org.apache.commons.logging.Log. I want to redirect the all the logs from A to a separate log file and am facing issues when I try to declare a custom appender and redirect logs from A in the log4j.xml.

How should I go about doing this? Please help.

Comment: what issues are you facing?  what does your current log4j.xml look like?  I see no reason why a custom appender would not be able to catch the messages from the A logs...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use slf4j for this. These library has bridges for legacy logging frameworks: http://www.slf4j.org/legacy.html and slf4j has implementation for different underlying logging frameworks. I never tried this but it should work:

commonslogging -> slf4j -> log4j